# Visual C++ not respecting alignment for stack variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following sometimes fails after compiling for x86 with Visual Studio 16.8.1:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

struct X { uint64_t value; };

int main() {
    X x;
    assert(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&x) % alignof(X) == 0);
}
```

Interestingly, the assert doesn't trigger if `X` has an explicit alignment specifier: `struct alignas(uint64_t) X`.

Am I correct to assume this is a compiler bug and not some quirk of the C++ standard?

Comment: maybe the quirk is in your expectations.  Why do you expect the assertion to hold?

Comment: I expect `x` to be placed in memory per its alignment requirement.

Comment: but the address of `x` is just some address, alignment with respect to what? (btw, I don't know what is happening here, I am just curious and look forward to answers)

Comment: Alignment requirement for struct is 32-bit in 32-bit build.

Comment: Alignment with respect to address `0`. If `x` has alignment `N`, I'd expect its address to be a multiple of `N`.

Comment: Quoting cppreference: "Every object type has the property called alignment requirement, which is an integer value (of type std::size_t, always a power of 2) representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which objects of this type can be allocated."

Comment: @Dialecticus `alignof(X)` is 8 regardless of 32-bit / 64-bit build.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920103/why-is-the-alignment-the-same-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-systems

Comment: Thanks, that does explain it. I'll try to summarize the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

On x86, some operations may incur a performance penalty unless the operand is naturally aligned. Apparently Visual C++ has a nonconformant `alignof` operator which returns the *natural* alignment instead of the *required* alignment for a type. When building with MSVC for 32-bit, the natural alignment of `uint64_t` / `double` is 8, while its required alignment is 4. So in the code above the address of `x` must be a multiple of 4, but not necessarily a multiple of `alignof(X)`.

This baffling behavior is underlined by `uint64_t x;` not having the same meaning as `alignas(uint64_t) uint64_t x;`. Only the latter has the expected alignment.

See also: GCC fixing a similar [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69560) and associated libc++ [updates](https://reviews.llvm.org/D54814).

Comment: Reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1258506/visual-c-alignof-is-not-conformant-on-x86.html).

Comment: Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-160#conflicts-with-the-x86-compiler).

Comment: Thanks for the link. This explains the alignment of stack variables on x86. But it doesn't address `alignof`, which should report the _required_ alignment of 4.